# Распарсить json средствами PHP

Tags: php, json

Получаю через CURL json output следующего вида: `[{"uid":123582,"password":"83584586"}]`

Как вывести `uid` и `password` соответственно в HTML?

```
$result = '[{"uid":1245,"password":"123123"}]'; 
$json = json_decode($result); 

print $json->{'uid'};
```

Выводит:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Всем спасибо за ответы

Comment: Версия `php` у вас какая ? (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [ ] в начале и конце строки `[{"uid":123582,"password":"83584586"}]` - это объявление массива. Т. е. объект находится в элементе массива. В приведенном Вами примере это выглядит так:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'uid' => int 1245
      public 'password' => string '123123' (length=6)
```

Соответственно, обращаться к данным следует как к элементу массива:

```
$json[0]->{'uid'}; //Если элемент всего один.
```

Если же элементов много, то их можно перебирать через foreach.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Answer (score 2):

У вас в json закодирован массив, соответственно, должно быть так:

```
print $json[0]->uid;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! :) все работает!